# How can I prevent file association from resetting: .R <> RStudio

Tags: finder

I would like to open .R files with RStudio on Mac. I tried several times setting it to RStudio as shown here: **Open With** > **Other** > **RStudio**, **Always Open With** checked.

But it keeps resetting it back to plain R. I don't run plain R **ever**. How can I track what's causing the reset and is there a way to set it programmatically in a configuration file?

[image: Screenshot of the contextual menu showing the Open With selection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Locate your **.R** file, from the Finder menu bar select **File** > **Get Info**.
2. In the **Get Info** window, move down to the section for **Open with:** and select the **RStudio.app**.
3. Just below the dropdown list, click on **Change All...**
4. You will get a dialog box that says:
   **Are you sure you want to change all similar documents to open with the application “RStudio”?

    This change will apply to all documents with extension ".R".**
5. Click **Continue**. This should set all **.R** files to open with **RStudio**.

(Here are sample screenshots using a text file named **text.txt**.

[image: Screenshot of the Get Info window]

[image: Screenshot of the dialog box to confirm changing the application]